# Locking Scale when Panning using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, zoom, navigation, pan

Is it possible to lock the scale of a map in ArcGIS Pro 2.9?

I'm manually editing a bunch of feature classes, so what I usually do is open the table, edit my field, then double click the next row number on the left side of the attribute table to pan to the next point.

Unfortunately, the default behavior is to pan and zoom when I do this.

I know I can do (CTRL + DOUBLE CLICK) to pan without zoom, but I'd hope I could make the default behavior to pan without the zoom.

I was able to accomplish this in ArcMap, so I thought ArcGIS Pro might have the feature as well but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - using Map Frame Constraints. Try the Fixed Scale option. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/customizing-your-map-extent.htm

Comment: It sounds like the asker is trying to do this in a Map view rather than in a Map Frame on a Layout.